# How to get only first level nodes with Jsoup

Tags: java, css, xml, jsoup

I have following XML tree and I'm using Jsoup to parse it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<nodes>
    <node>
        <name>NODE 1</name>
        <value1>
            <value1>NODE 1 VALUE 1</value1>
        </value1>
        <nodes>
            <node>
                <name>NODE 1 CHILD</name>
                <value1>NODE 1 CHILD VALUE 1</value1>
            </node>
        </nodes>
    </node>
    <node>
        <name>NODE 2</name>
        <value1>NODE 2 VALUE 1</value1>
    </node>
</nodes>
```

However when I try to get only first level of node-elements. It returns all elements including children nodes, and it is doing it correctly, because clearly child elements also match my query.

```
Elements elements = data.select("nodes > node");
```

Is there any way to get just first level node-elements without adding additional level information to XML data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Elements elements = data.select("nodes").first().select("> node");
```

This will work as well:

```
Elements elements = data.select("> nodes > node");
```

but only if you've used `Jsoup.parse(xml, "", Parser.xmlParser())` to parse the XML and the XML is indeed as you've specified in your question (`<nodes>` is the root element)

Comment: Your answer works. However what I actually needed was int depth = e.parents().size(); With this I can know correct depth.